# how to make the below piece of code work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I kind of wrote this piece of code:

```
import csv
import os
fileobj = csv.reader(open('c:\\paths1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in fileobj:
    x=0 

    for x in fileobj:
        filesize= os.path.getsize(x)

    print (filesize);
```

However I'm still receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\test1py\Acol.py", line 9, in <module>
    filesize= os.path.getsize(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I guess it's cos' fileobj contains a list of path...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
for x in row: # NOT   in fileobj
    filesize = os.path.getsize(x)
```

By the way, the line `x = 0` has no effect but to confuse the unsuspecting reader. You should remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! amazing!!! and sorry about the mistake but I started programming in python yesterday, I used to program in other programming languages that require that kind of thing... Anyway thanks again

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It sounds like this answer solved your problem. If that's the case, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).